# Measurability of product space function $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^D \times D \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $D$ be a (possibly uncountable) compact topological space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(D)$.

Let the space of functions from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}$
$$ \mathbb{R}^{D}: = \{f \mid f : D \to \mathbb{R} \} $$
be equipped by the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{R}^{D})$, which is generated by all the projection maps 
$$j_{\pi} : \mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad j_\pi (f) = f(\pi)$$
for $\pi \in D$.

Now let us define a map
$$ \Phi : \mathbb{R}^D \times D \to \mathbb{R}, \quad \Phi(f,\pi) = f(\pi)  .$$

Is it true, that $\Phi$ is $(\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{R}^{D}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(D))/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable? How could I show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not measurable. If it is measurable the its section $\pi \to f(\pi)$ would be a measurable map from $D$ to $\mathbb R$ for any fixed $f \in \mathbb R^{D}$.  But $f:D \to \mathbb R$ is an arbitrary function so it need not be Borel measurable.

Comment: Thanks! What happens if I change $\mathbb{R}^D$ to be the space of measurable functions, again with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the projections? Can I then make $\Phi$ measurable?

Comment: I think the answer is still no, but I don't have an example at the moment.